# Implementation pattern of object composition

Tags: c#, orm

I'm having trouble mapping these classes:

- **Order**
- **Pallet**
- **Box**

Together they form a relationship of composition, detailed in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

An instance of class **Order** has several **Pallet** objects, which has several **Box** objects.

This is what I have now:

```
class Order
{
    public Order(){}
    private List<Pallet> _pallets = new List<Pallet>;
    public Pallet Add_pallet()
    {
        Pallet new_pallet = new Pallet(this);
        this._pallets.Add(new_pallet);
        return new_pallet;
    }
    //...other properties and methods...
}
```

---

```
class Pallet
{
    private Order _parent_order;
    private List<Box> _boxes = new List<Box>;
    public Pallet(Order parent_order)
    {
        _parent_order = parent_order;
    }
    public Box Add_Box()
    {
        Box new_box = new Box(this);
        this._boxes.Add(new_box);
        return new_box;
    }
    //...other properties and methods...
}
```

---

```
class Box
{
    private Pallet _parent_pallet;
    public Box(Pallet parent_pallet){}
    //...other properties and methods...
}
```

All **Boxes** must belong to a **Pallet** and all **Pallets** must belong to an **Order**.
How can I implement this correctly to avoid this:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Order myOrder = new Order();
        Pallet myPallet = new Pallet(myOrder);
        //Now I have a Pallet that belongs to an Order,
        //but the Order object is not aware of it
    }
}
```

Should I use nested classes or is there something more useful I am missing?

Comment: Does your Pallet and Box really need to know which Order and Pallet respectively they belong to? These circular dependencies will probably give garbage collector a headache. Maybe it would be better to outsource the relation bookkeeping to an external entity?

Comment: That can be a way to simplify things, but I could still create Boxes that don't actually belong to a Pallet and the problem would still exist.

Comment: It would appear to me, in this situation, composition isn't the correct approach. A `Pallet` / `Box` could almost certainly exist on their own therefore I think aggregation would be more suited here.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
public class Order
{
    private List<Pallet> _pallets = new List<Pallet>;
    internal void Add_pallet(Pallet pallet)
    {
        if (!this._pallets.Contains(pallet))
            this._pallets.Add(pallet);
    }
    //...other properties and methods...
}

public class Pallet
{
    private Order _parent_order;
    private List<Box> _boxes = new List<Box>;
    public Pallet(Order parent_order)
    {
        if (parent_order = null)
            throw ArgumentNilException("parent_order must not be null");
        _parent_order = parent_order;
        _parent_order.Add_pallet(this);
    }
    //...other properties and methods...
}
```

aso.